# Doctrine2 Criteria convert 1 to TRUE

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I've got a problem with Criteria from Doctrine2. Iusing Criteria to check a SMALLINT type in PostreSQL like this :

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("actif", 1));
return $this->c_Agenda->matching($criteria);
```

But I've got this error :

> Invalid input syntax for integer: "t"

I suppose criteria convert 1 in TRUE and PostreSQL dosen't recognize this value. If I change 1 to 0 I've got the same error but with f instead of t.

In PostreSQL, actif type is SMALLINT.

Comment: as hack you can try changing `eq("actif", 1)` to `eq("actif::boolean", 1)`. not a solution - just curious

Comment: I've got this error : Unrecognize field actif::boolean

Comment: thought so... you can "hack" select 0::boolean to return false in postgres, and all other positive integers to return true, but better of course unify attribute type in db with it in Doctrine2...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Criteria::expr()->eq("actif", 1)` with `Criteria::expr()->eq("actif", "1")`